# Beginner JavaScript, JSON indexing question: why is my (for ... in) script failing?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, indexing

I am not a seasoned Javascript coder or even too familiar with JSON. My approach is likely very naive. Recommendations for better approaches are welcome.

Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      database = {
        "name": "AdventureWorks2012 vs AdventureWorksModified",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Person",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Address",                     
            "children": [{
              "name": "AddressID",
              "attributes": {
                "coltype": "int",
                "coldefault": null,
                "colordinal": 1,
                "colCharLength": null
              }
            }]
          },{
            "name": "Address",                     
            "children": [{
              "name": "AddressID",
              "attributes": {
                "coltype": "int",
                "coldefault": null,
                "colordinal": 1,
                "colCharLength": null
              }
            }]
          }]
        },{
          "name": "PersonDELETEmePLEASE",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Address",                     
            "children": [{
              "name": "AddressID",
              "attributes": {
                "coltype": "int",
                "coldefault": null,
                "colordinal": 1,
                "colCharLength": null
              }
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }

      console.log(`name : ${database.name}`);
      console.log("=SCHEMAS=");
      for (var i in database.children){
        console.log(`name : ${database.children[i].name}`);
        console.log("children: (-TABLES-)");  

        for (var j in database.children){
          console.log(`name : ${database.children[i].children[j].name}`);
          console.log("children: (-COLUMNS-)");

          for (var k in database.children[i].children[j].children){
            console.log(`name : ${database.children[i].children[j].children[k].name}`);
            console.log("children: (-DATA-)");

            for (var l in database.children[i].children[j].children[k].attributes){
              console.log(`${l} : ${database.children[i].children[j].children[k].attributes[l]}`);
            }
          }
        }
        console.log("\n\n\n");  
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The structure is database -> schemas -> tables -> columns + column data.

AdventureWorks2012 vs AdventureWorksModified -> Person -> Address -> AddressID + attributes.

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to iterate through some JSON data. Whether if outputted to HTML or to the console, I run into an error on a strange condition: whenever a schema has just ONE table. It can have one child, or one data member, but it MUST have more than one table.

This is the error I get:

[image: This is the error I get.]

Please aid my understanding: what's in my looping causes this to happen? I want to ask before I start looking for workarounds and end up leading myself into a ditch.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In your second for loop (`for (var j in database.children)`) i believe it should read `for (var j in database.children[i].children)`

Comment: FYI: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. What you have there is just an object.

Comment: That is not JSON, it is a JavaScript object literal.  JSON is always a string.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarifications. I'll keep these in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two loops loop over the same thing

```
for (var i in database.children) { <-- same
  for (var j in database.children) <-- same
```

You forgot to reference the nesting

```
for (var i in database.children) { <-- first level
  for (var j in database.children[i].children) <-- second level
    console.log(database.children[i].children[j])
```

Comment: Oh wow, I am a dense oatmeal cookie. Thank you a ton good sir.